# java print pattern for loop

Tags: java, for-loop

I have search far and wide for a solution for this problem I am having. Im on the right track (I think) but not thinking some logic out properly so wondering if I could get some help for this.

```
  for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
  {
     for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
     {
        System.out.print(" ");
     }
     System.out.println("#");

  }
  for (int l = 0; l < 6; l++)
  {
     for (int m = 6; m > l; m--)
     {

        System.out.print(" ");
     }
     System.out.println("#");

  }

Output: #
         #
          #
           #
            #
             #
              #
             #
            #
           #
          #
         #
```

What I am trying to achieve is 
`output: 
         #           #
          #         # #
           #       #   #
            #     #     #
             #   #       #
              # #         #
               #           #`

Comment: Hint: You have to think ahead what a row would look like since every `println` moves you to the next row.

Comment: not sure, when I was on computer the desired output looked correct, but on mobile it looks wonky. It should be in the shape of the letter 'V'   also thank you reut, I'm thinking about how to code this while in health class now. hopefully will produce working code soon

Answer (score 0):

Here's some help, in clear and highlighted steps, so you can read the first and try, before going to the next... To avoid spoiling the solution :)

## Help 1

Observe that the pattern is kinda regular, but there's some "noise" in the beginning of each row... To start, try to avoid printing the initial spaces. Instead of

```
     #           #
      #         # #
       #       #   #
        #     #     #
         #   #       #
          # #         #
           #           #
```

consider

```
     #           #
     #         # #
     #       #   #
     #     #     #
     #   #       #
     # #         #
     #           #
```

## Help 2

Clearly, each row has the same size from the first `#` to the last `#`. So, you have to "move the one in the middle. Basically, this means that every line is composed by a fixed `#`, spaces, a movable `#`, spaces, another fixed `#`.

## Help 3

How do you "move" the middle one? Does the *total* number of spaces change? The number of spaces between the first and the last `#` does not change.
Hence, you have a fixed amount of spaces (e.g. 10), but you insert something in between. The pattern of spaces will go something like this: 0#10, 1#9, 2#8, ..., 9#1, 10#0. How do you do that with a single loop?

Answer (score 0):

I won't address what the solution is to produce the desired graph. Instead, I would like to comment on several errors in your original code.

The code you post has 2 main for loops. Each, according to the condition you set:

```
int i = 0; i < 6; i++
```

will cause

```
System.out.println("#");
```

to print 6 "#" on six different lines.

Since you have two for loops performing println(), they will cause the program to display 12 lines in total regardless of the sub-for loops in each main for loop, because the sub-for loop is only used to displaying white spaces before a "#" is printed.

Answer (score 0):

store the output in a char double array and then replace spots as you travel through the array.

```
int height = 6;
int peeks = 5;
// the top and bottom peaks share a point with eachother
// so for every down and up there are "2*height - 2" points
// the last peak has no connection, so add 1
int duration = (peeks*2*(height - 1)) + 1;

// create a double array and fill it with spaces
char[][] output = new char[height][duration];
for(int i = 0; i < height; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < duration; j++){
        output[i][j] = ' ';
    }
}

// keep track of if we are going up or down
boolean increment = true;

for(int distance = 0, level = 0; distance < duration; distance++){
    // mark every point in the path
    output[level][distance] = '#';
    if (level == 0){
        increment = true;
    }
    else if (level == height -1){
        increment = false;
    }
    level += increment? 1 : -1;
}

// print each line in the double array
for(int i = 0; i < output.length; i++){
    System.out.println(String.valueOf(output[i]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there is a more elegant solution, but here is some kind of brute alg that has the exact output that you requested:

```
   int spaceCount1 = 9;
   int spaceCount2 = 11;
   int spaceCount3 = 0;
   int j = 1;
   for(int row = 0; row < 7; row++){
       System.out.println();
       for(int i = 0; i < spaceCount1; i++){
           System.out.print(" ");
       }
       spaceCount1++;
       for(j = 1; j <= 1; j++){
            System.out.print("#");
       }
       j--;
       for(int i = spaceCount2; i > 0; i--){
            System.out.print(" ");
       }
       spaceCount2 -= 2;

       for(j = 1; j <= 1 && row < 6; j++){
            System.out.print("#");
       }
       j--;
       for(int i = 1; i < spaceCount3 ; i++){
           System.out.print(" ");
       }
       spaceCount3 += 2;
       for(j = 1; j <= 1 && row > 0; j++){
           System.out.print("#");
       }
       j--;
  }
```

output:

```
     #           #
      #         # #
       #       #   #
        #     #     #
         #   #       #
          # #         #
           #           #
```